# Drawing an adjustable rectangle in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, draw

I have this code that I have obtained sometime ago from this site (sorry I don't know the exact source). It allows me to create a multiple choice answer sheet.

I have modified it to some extent and would like to know how do I draw an adjustable rectangle around the bubbles as shown below.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\encircle[2][]{% 
    \indent\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
    \node (X)    [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=1pt, #1] {\strut$#2$};
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\answerspace}[1]{%
    
            \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}  {%
            \noindent\hspace*{10mm}\llap{\textbf{\x}}\hspace{5mm}\space
            \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4} {% 
                \l_encircle {\x}{\y} \ %
            }\newline\newline%
        }%

    }


\cs_new_protected:Npn \l_encircle #1#2 {    { \encircle{\int_to_Alph:n{#2}} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\normalsize 
\answerspace{24}
\end{multicols}

\end{center}



\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep using your code, then this solution works.

Basically I renamed your command to something else, and put it inside of another `\newcommand` that will add the boxes later, which you can customize by changing the border color or width.

I added a counter to your `\foreach` commands and used those to rename your nodes as `row-column` for better reference. Then I used those to get the anchors needed for the boxes.

This solution assumes:

- that you will keep using 4 answers, i.e. `A, B, C, D`
- that you will keep using this format for the cheatsheet

So if you want further customisation, that's possible but I'd rather rebuild your code from scratch so that I'm sure it's robust and works for other use cases.

**Note:** If you change the number of questions, you need to compile twice!

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\encircle[2][]{% 
    \indent\tikz[baseline=(\nx-\ny.base), remember picture]{
    \node (\nx-\ny) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=10pt, #1] 
    {\strut$#2$};
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\createrows}[1]{%
            \foreach \x [count=\nx] in {1,...,#1}  {%
            \noindent\hspace*{10mm}\llap{\textbf{\x}}\hspace{5mm}\space
            \foreach \y [count=\ny] in {1,2,3,4} {% 
                \l_encircle {\x}{\y} \ %
            }\newline\newline%
        }%
    }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l_encircle #1#2 {    { \encircle{\int_to_Alph:n{#2}} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\answerspace[2][]{%
\createrows{#2}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\halfofrows{#2/2}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\secondhalfofrows{#2/2+1}
    \draw[line width=1pt,#1] (1-1.north west) rectangle (\halfofrows-4.south east);
    \draw[line width=1pt,#1] (\secondhalfofrows-1.north west) rectangle (#2-4.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \centering
\normalsize 
\answerspace{24}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Alenanno Thanks for that, I noticed you used two rectangles that overlap. Quick question, where can I learn how to create macros in LaTeX? Do you know a source/website?

Comment: @AlanJones Where do they overlap? Well, I learned most of it on this website.

Comment: They over lap when I try to generate a ```\answerspace{10}``` without ```\multicols{}```

Comment: @AlanJones ah ok, that's why I said that it was based on your code. If you want it more dynamic I might need to rebuild the code from scratch. To fix it quickly though, you can delete the second rectangle, and give the second coordinates of the deleted rectangle to the one that stayed.